# Negative coefficient for dummy variable regression analysis

Tags: regression, dummy-variable, coefficients

I am interpreting multiple regression analysis with the dependent variable being rate of return (ROR) on a stock. Also, I have included a dummy-variable that represents the stock getting included and excluded out of an index (1 = included, 0 = excluded). 
The output showed a negative coefficient-value (the value is -0,03852),  and I´m not quite sure how to make of this. Does this mean that being included in an index has a negative effect on the dependent variable?

Could someone please provide me an "easy" explanation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means when the stock is included (value of 1), you expect the rate of return to decrease by 0.03852. More or less, i guess you can call it a negative effect. What you should check is whether this coefficient is significant or what is the standard error of this coefficient. Usually regression tools should provide that.